# Adding windows capabilities to Windows server core running in docker

Tags: windows, powershell, docker

I am running the `microsoft/windowsservercore:1803` in docker:

```
docker run -it microsoft/windowsservercore:1803
```

inside it, I start powershell and run the `Get-WindowsCapability` cmdlet and get the following output:

```
PS C:\> Get-WindowsCapability -online
Get-WindowsCapability : The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WindowsCapability -online
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WindowsCapability], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.GetWindowsCapabilityCommand
```

What service it refers to? Can I set up the container so it would allow me to run that, or `Add-WindowsCapability` cmdlets?

Ultimately, I want to run [officially distributed by Microsoft] OpenSSH server.

**Update**. I checked the status of Windows Update and TrustedInstaller services in the container (as were suggested in the comments): the former was disabled, so I enabled it:

```
Set-Service -Name wuauserv -StartupType Manual
Start-Service -name wuauserv
```

And tried running `Get-WindowsCapability` again:

```
PS C:\> Get-WindowsCapability -online
Get-WindowsCapability : Get-WindowsCapability failed. Error code = 0x80d03805
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WindowsCapability -online
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WindowsCapability], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.GetWindowsCapabilityCommand
```

Still does not work, but error is now different.

This is what I see in the EventLog:

```
PS C:\> Get-EventLog system

   Index Time          EntryType   Source                 InstanceID Message
   ----- ----          ---------   ------                 ---------- -------
     312 Jun 24 14:07  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Windows Update service entered the stopped state.
     311 Jun 24 14:01  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Remote Registry service entered the stopped state.
     310 Jun 24 13:59  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Windows Error Reporting Service service entered the stopped state.
     309 Jun 24 13:59  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Windows Modules Installer service entered the stopped state.
     308 Jun 24 13:57  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Windows Error Reporting Service service entered the running state.
     307 Jun 24 13:57  Error       DCOM                        10001 The description for Event ID '10001' in Source 'DCOM' cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may not have permission to access them.  The following information is part of the event:'C:\Windows\system32\...
     306 Jun 24 13:57  Error       DCOM                        10001 The description for Event ID '10001' in Source 'DCOM' cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may not have permission to access them.  The following information is part of the event:'C:\Windows\system32\...
     305 Jun 24 13:57  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Delivery Optimization service entered the running state.
     304 Jun 24 13:57  Information Microsoft-Windows...           44 Windows Update started downloading an update.
     303 Jun 24 13:57  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Windows Modules Installer service entered the running state.
     302 Jun 24 13:57  Information Service Control M...   1073748860 The Windows Update service entered the running state.
```

The two error messages are:

> The description for Event ID '10001' in Source 'DCOM' cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may not have permission to access them.  The following information is part of the event:'C:\Windows\system32\DllHost.exe
>   /Processid:{AA65DD7C-83AC-48C0-A6FD-9B61FEBF8800}', '0', '{AA65DD7C-83AC-48C0-A6FD-9B61FEBF8800}', 'Unavailable', 'Unavailable'
>
> The description for Event ID '10001' in Source 'DCOM' cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may not have permission to access them.  The following information is part of the event:'C:\Windows\system32\DllHost.ex
>   /Processid:{AA65DD7C-83AC-48C0-A6FD-9B61FEBF8800}', '1008', '{AA65DD7C-83AC-48C0-A6FD-9B61FEBF8800}', 'Unavailable', 'Unavailable'

Comment: Try `Get-Service |? StartType -eq Disabled` and see if the Windows Update or TrustedInstaller service is in the list.  If so, try changing the start type, starting it, and trying `Get-WindowsCapability` again.  That said, I don't know if there's a good reason that it would have been disabled in the first place in a Docker container.

Comment: @MatthewWetmore, thanks for the suggestion. See the update above, something's changed, but it still does not work.

Comment: I'd suggest looking in %windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log and %windir%\logs\dism\dism.log and search for ", error"  (without the quotes.- comma space error" and see if anything looks obvious.  "error" (without the comma and space) will be in multiple other messages, but aren't interesting.  There's a good chance this isn't supported, but this isn't my area.

Comment: Some conventional wisdom is to add capabilities and updates to your base image instead of the container, but I don't have confirmation on that. I'm asking around a bit, but no guarantee I'll get a definitive answer.